# Pass and modifiy class passing in express router

Tags: node.js, express, class, express-router

I would like pass a class to an express router, and modify my class to each request.

server.ts

```
import routes from './routes';
import Client from './client';

class Server {
    constructor () {
        this.app = express()
        this.client = new Client();
        this.init()
    }

    init() {
        this.app.use(routes(this))
    }
}
```

routes.ts

```
import {Router} from 'express';

export default (api) => {
    const router = Router();
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        api.client.size+=1;
        console.log(api.client.size);
    });
    return router;
}
```

It's similar to this problem : [Pass variable to express router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996082/pass-variable-to-express-router)

But this code doesn't work.

Somebody has an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the class you passed? What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is the answer to my question :

server.js

```
class Server {
    constructor () {
        this.app = express();
        this.app.locals.clients = new Clients();
    }
}
```

route.ts

```
import {Router} from 'express';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.app.locals.client.size += 1;
    res.send(`bla bla bla`);
});

export default router;
```